# Retornar ID de quem tem a menor distancia entre as coordenadas

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, angularjs, ionic

tenho uma função em ajax que retorna todas as latitudes e longitudes dos usuários cadastrados no banco de dados e me da a menor distancia entre as coordenadas retornadas e uma coordenada fixa no código , funciona muito bem ele me da o menor valor, o problema é que eu preciso saber qual é o  ID desse usuário que tem a coordenada de menor distância, não tenho a menor ideia de como fazer isso , já tentei dar um return no ID mas ele retorna o menor ID e não o ID da menor coordenada.

Aqui está o meu código ajax

```
$.ajax({


  type : 'POST',
  data : formula,
  url : 'http://10.0.0.119/melleve/statusorig2.php',
  success : function(data){


    var retorno = JSON.parse(data);




var testandoisso = $.map(retorno, function (value) {

  var latitude = value.latitude;
  var longitude = value.longitude;
  var id = value.idmoto;



var lat1 = -22.8650697;
var lat2 = latitude;

var long1 = -43.287510499999996;
var long2 = longitude;

var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180;
var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180;
var theta = long1 - long2;
var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180;
var dist = Math.sin(radlat1)*Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
dist = Math.acos(dist);

dist = dist * 180/Math.PI;
dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;


var finaldist = dist * 1.609344;


return finaldist;


});

var ok = Math.min.apply(Math, testandoisso);

     console.log(ok);



  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    //debugger;
  }
  //,complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
   // debugger;
  //}

})
```

desde já , muito obrigado a todos.

console.log(ok) escreve na console do meu navegador o valor da menor distância , eu preciso que ele me retorne o ID de quem tem a menor distância.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O `min.apply` não vai te ajudar neste caso, pois retorna apenas um valor. Você teria que criar uma estrutura com `distância, id`, e retornar ambos.

Veja um exemplo funcional:
<sub>(dei uma enxugada no código para poder mostrar aqui no próprio SOpt)</sub>

```js
var retorno = [
    { "latitude":-23, "longitude":-49, "idmoto":1 },
    { "latitude":-22, "longitude":-47, "idmoto":2 },
    { "latitude":-25, "longitude":-49, "idmoto":3 },
    { "latitude":-22, "longitude":-43, "idmoto":4 }, // O mais próximo do Botafogo - N.I.
    { "latitude":-24, "longitude":-48, "idmoto":5 }, 
    { "latitude":-21, "longitude":-40, "idmoto":6 },
    { "latitude":-22, "longitude":-48, "idmoto":7 },
    { "latitude":-20, "longitude":-38, "idmoto":8 }
  ];
  
var testandoisso = retorno.map( function (value) {
  var lat1  = -22.8650697;
  var long1 = -43.287510499999996;

  var lat2  = value.latitude;
  var long2 = value.longitude;

  var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180;
  var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180;
  var theta = long1 - long2;
  var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180;
  var dist = Math.acos( Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2)
    + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta) )
    * (180/Math.PI)  * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344;

  return { 'distancia':dist, 'id':value.idmoto };
} );

var escolhido = { 'distancia':Infinity, 'id':0 };
for(var i = 0; i < testandoisso.length; i++ ) {
  if ( testandoisso[i]['distancia'] < escolhido['distancia'] ) escolhido = testandoisso[i];
}

// Mostrando o resultado:
document.body.innerHTML += 'Id:'   + escolhido['id']        + '<br>';
document.body.innerHTML += 'Dist:' + escolhido['distancia'] + '<br>';
```

Comment: *o* nossa. nice.

Comment: muito bom funciona corretamente , obrigado amigo.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode guardar o valor do ID do usuário em uma variável externa, que vai ser atualizada toda vez que a sua função encontrar a menor distancia, assim quando você chamar a função e ela retornar o valor, você pode acessar a variável.